# HTTP/2 Server Push and Browser Cache

Tags: server, push, browser-cache, http2

I read some documents about HTTP/2 Server Push.

A blog owner said that:

> However, there is a very headache problem in server push. If the browser has already cached the resource files which are to be pushed, pushing is just a waste of bandwidth.

Another one said:

> Since server push will send the assets to the client as distinct HTTP objects (each with its own Cache-Control headers), they can be cached by the browser just like anything else.

**My question is that**, HTTP/2 Push and browser cache both are working well? Or If I activate HTTP/2 Push feature for some assets, browser cache won't work for these assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you push a resource and the page needs to use it, it will be saved to the browser cache for next time.

The problem lies if you change the resource, and push it again, but the old version is already in the browser cache and the cache control headers say it’s still valid, then the browser will use the old cached version despite the fact you have pushed a newer version. So it’s a wasted push.

Good blog post on it [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/) and [here](https://blog.yoav.ws/tale-of-four-caches/) and also [Chapter 5 of my book](https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action?a_aid=tunetheweb&a_bid=a810f9b6) due out soon covers this too.

Comment: Thank you @Barry Pollard,

I will push combined css only in the html. So I will defer other assets like js, woff2, images via Cloudflare Rocket Loader. If I do that, my webpage is loading within 350ms. If I don't do that, the page is loading between 300-600 ms.

I really appreciate it! Thank you again!

Comment: Ok but if you visit the page again, then you really should try to avoid pushing again. You can use a cookie based method to do this: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/http2-push/.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Cloudflare "cache everything" rule. So cookies will be overridden by CF. @BarryPollard So I can't use this pushing feature I guess...

Comment: What is "a wasted push"? Other than the couple dozen bytes header there is no waste.

Comment: If you push you push the header AND the body. In theory after getting the PUSH_PROMISE frame the browser can cancel it and say “no thanks - got that one already”, but in practice the resource will already have been sent and will be on the way so client gets full cost of the water push.